# Count all rows past a certain DateTime in a SQL query in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, ms-access-2010

I have this SQL query that I'm trying to have count all the rows which have an `OrderDate` value larger than the `StartDate` value:

```
"SELECT COUNT(*), OrderDate 
 FROM Orders 
 WHERE OrderDate >= '"+StartDate+"'"
```

The error I get is

> You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'OrderDate' as part of an aggregate function.

The structure of the `Orders` table is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGhLo.png

Comment: why are you selecting orderdate ? just use count(*) and you'll get the result.

Comment: Please consider using a `Parameterized` query instead of inline variables

Answer (score 1):

try to convert `OrderDate` to string. And you can use string interpolation in creating the query string

```
    $"SELECT 
     COUNT(*), 
     OrderDate 
    FROM 
     Orders
    WHERE
     CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), OrderDate, 121) >= '{StartDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")}'
    GROUP BY
     OrderDate
```

> Note: StartDate must have yyyy-MM-dd format. if that is a `DateTime` variable you can parse it out using `.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")`

Answer (score 1):

Turns out my problem was I was missing # before and after the StartDate, ms access needs it to accept datetime into string or something I suppose

Answer (score 1):

You need a string expression for your date value, and no OrderDate:

```
"SELECT COUNT(*)
 FROM Orders 
 WHERE OrderDate >= #" + StartDate.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd") + "#"
```